# C# Word Interop Table alignment issue, while moving to server below code not able to resize the table cell

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

This is my code:

```cs
Private void TAbleconvertion () {
   // Table alignment issue
   for (int TableCount = 1; TableCount <= wdDocConv.Tables.Count; TableCount++) {
       if (wdDocConv.Tables[TableCount] != null) {
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table tbl = wdDocConv.Tables[TableCount];
    
           tbl.AllowAutoFit = true;
           Range r = tbl.Range;
           Cells cells = r.Cells;
           for (int count = 1; count <= cells.Count; count++) {
               // Resizing width - but not working when this code move to windows server
               int size = 100 / cells.Count;
               Cell cell = cells[count];
               cell.PreferredWidth = size;
               cells.PreferredWidth = size;
               Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Word interop does not work on servers. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2. I recommend using a library from microsoft that does work with word docx files and a server like  openXML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: Also you need to add more details about what is "not working" about it. Are you getting a error? does it try and no edit happens? Add more details